# How do I show :before pseudo-element with negative absolute position in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I have an absolute positioned `::before` pseudo-element that I am trying to add an arrow above with CSS.  Specifically this arrow appears on hover.

In all browsers except IE, this works fine.  In IE, the pseudo-element appears on hover but is "behind" the button's parent `div`.  This makes it appear as if the arrow doesn't show at all.

The z-index property seems to have no effect.  I have a jsfiddle set up here:

https://jsfiddle.net/gk8rsjkp/

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this with a similar problem:

Using an actual `button` element caused the issue. Switching to a `div` solved the problem.  This quirk seems to be limited to IE.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, you must declare the :hover as well as the :hover:before.

```css
button:hover { } /* IE needs this to trigger the :hover:before */
button:hover:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

button {
  position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 36px;
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>
    Button
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This does seem to be a solution for a hover pseudo-element not applying at all in IE.  However, my problem turned out to be the button element.  Switching to a div solved the problem.